# How to create empty data table using PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am creating a UI that allows users to input data in batches.

Similar to an Excel spreadsheet but the columns are already fixed.

I'm already using PrimeNG DataTable for other parts of my web app, and I would like to continue using it for the aforementioned feature if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

My initial code was correct but because there was an issue when the backing array of the data table was being updated via push.

I had to create a separate array with the empty objects and assign it to the backing array.